# What is the corresponding linear system to the blowup of a surface?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Suppose we have a smooth projective surface $S$, $p$ is a point on this surface. We blowup $S$ at this point by $\pi:\tilde{S}\to S$. Then $\pi$ is a birational morphism. By which linear system $\pi$ is given?

Answer (score 0):

The morphism coming from a linear system is a morphism from to the Blow-up of the base locus of the system, so you have to take the system of divisors going through $p$. See the wikipedia [entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_system_of_divisors) for linear systems, for instance

Comment: Suppose $E$ is an exceptional divisor, is it true that the desired linear system is $|-E|$, or am I missing something?